# How can I prevent Adobe Acrobat from automatically updating?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

How can I prevent Adobe Acrobat from automatically updating?

[image]

I don't see any option in the Adobe Creative Cloud:

[image]

The preferences only mention Adobe Creative Cloud, and not the Adobe programs:

[image]

Comment: Creative cloud is the entire suite of apps. Maybe that option you show is the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be configured in Adobe Acrobat (and not ion in the Adobe Creative Cloud):

[image]

[image]